# Convert data from Unicode to Ascii in Sql server

Tags: sql-server

my table have data in nvarchar like

```
N'Việt nam dân chủ cộng hòa'

declare @string_in nvarchar(55)
set @string_in = N'Việt nam dân chủ cộng hòa'

select @string_In [@string_In]
```

and I want convert my data from `N'Việt nam dân chủ cộng hòa'` to `"Viet nam dan chu cong hoa"`.

How can I do that?
thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I see is using `REPLACE()` function and replace the specific character cause even `COLLATE` didn't help in recognizing the character. (There may be a better solution present).

```
declare @string_in nvarchar(55) 
set @string_in = N'Việt nam dân chủ cộng hòa'
  //Didn't Work
select cast(@string_in Collate Latin1_General_CS_AS as varchar(55))
```

This one worked returning `Viet nam dan chu cong hoa`

```
select  replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@string_in,N'ệ','e'),N'â','a'),N'ủ','u'),N'ộ','o'),N'ò','o')
```

Comment: It's a good start but if [default] database collation is case insensitive and if `@string_in` is `N'VIỆT NAM DÂN CHỦ CỘNG HÒA'` then the results will be `VIeT NAM DaN CHu CoNG HoA` (it should be `VIET NAM DAN CHU CONG HOA`).

Comment: @BogdanSahlean, that is but per post `@string_in` is not in upper case though and it works perfectly per posted information. there may be a better solution (I did already mention that in answer) but this is what I can see as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an extension of Rahul's method, specifing a case-sensitive collation and additional replace functions for uppercase characters.

```
select  replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@string_in COLLATE Vietnamese_CS_AS,N'ệ','e'),N'â','a'),N'ủ','u'),N'ộ','o'),N'ò','o'),N'Ệ','E'),N'Â','A'),N'Ủ','U'),N'Ộ','O'),N'Ò','O')
```